# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller]

Tags: spring

On injecting jaxb2Marshaller getting the below exception

No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
@Autowired
private Jaxb2Marshaller  jaxb2Marshaller; 

public Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Marshaller() {
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}

public void setJaxb2Marshaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller) {
    this.jaxb2Marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

getJaxb2Marshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getData().getBytes())));

Can anyone suggest how to inject the jaxb2Marshaller ??

Comment: Do you prpper configure the Jaxb2Marshall bean? Check the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-jaxb2

Comment: I would like to use the annotations instead of xml based configuration.

Comment: could you please suggest how to configure the bean using annotations